# How to extract PKCS12 keystore(containing a keypair of pkcs#8 and a certificate)

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, android-keystore

when the user provides keystore, usually the keystore contains a keypair(an RSA encrypted private key, x.509 certificate) and CA certificates.
I want to extract the contents of keystore and write them in a different file.

I am able to read the contents of certificates without any issue but when trying to read the key and write to file, the contents are in unecrypted form.

How to write the contents of private key file in encrypted from itself?

I have fetched the key and cert as below:

```
key = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, password.toCharArray());
cert = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias);
```

I also tried using bouncycastle.

Using java libs:

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key.getEncoded());
byte[] privatekey = encoder.encode(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
```

Using bouncycastle:

```
 JceOpenSSLPKCS8EncryptorBuilder encryptorBuilder = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8EncryptorBuilder(PKCS8Generator.PBE_SHA1_RC2_128);  
 encryptorBuilder.setRandom(new SecureRandom());  
 encryptorBuilder.setPasssword("abcde".toCharArray()); // password  
 OutputEncryptor encryptor = encryptorBuilder.build();  

 JcaPKCS8Generator gen2 = new JcaPKCS8Generator(key, encryptor);  
 PemObject obj2 = gen2.generate();  
 StringWriter sw2 = new StringWriter();  
 try (JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw2)) {  
   pw.writeObject(obj2);  
 }  
 String pkcs8Key2 = sw2.toString();  
 FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyLocation);  
 fos2.write(pkcs8Key2.getBytes());  
 fos2.flush();  
 fos2.close();
```

when used plain java libs the content is decrypted and I may want to append the header and footer tags.

When used bouncy castle, I got some data with in `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` but the content is not same as the original file. I also tried using different PKCS8Gnerator.algorithms to no use.

Comment: There are several dozen formats for privatekey-only files, some encrypted, and about half of them supported by BouncyCastle. The format your code wrote, PKCS8 encrypted PEM, is a valid one among many. If it's not suitable for some reason, you need to be much more clear about what you do want. Note that any privatekey-only file will differ structurally from PKCS12 (or other Java keystore file), and even two encrypted privatekey files in the same format will differ in the encryption used because proper password-based encryption is salted, and even plain symmetric encryption is randomized.

Comment: All I want is read an encrypted private key present in a keystore and write its contents to a file

Comment: If you want to read the encryption of the privatekey stored in PKCS12 (in the 'shroudedKeyBag') look at BouncyCastle. If you want to read the encryption of the privatekey stored in JKS that's unsupported, plus no other software anywhere will be able to use the result, because although it's PKCS8 _format_ it's totally nonstandard proprietary _encryption_. If what you want is a file containing _an_ encryption of the privatekey, but not the _same_ encryption, your code already does that.

Comment: Thanks your correct my code is working fine.